# Mimic double-press of UITabBarController to root view controller

Tags: ios, swift

For my app I made a custom menu for iPads to replace the UITabBarController which I'm using for iPhones. And it works great, except that when I click a tab it takes me to that tab and remembers state. I want it instead to take me to the main navigation controller for the tab (the immediate child of the UITabBarController, of which there are four), forgetting about where I was last, exactly like what happens if you press twice on a native tab bar item. Any ideas?

In AppDelegate.swift I have

```
if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Pad{
 this_is_an_ipad = true
}
```

In MainTabBarController.swift I have

```
class MainTabBarController: UITabBarController {
 override func viewWillLayoutSubviews(){
    if this_is_an_ipad{
        self.tabBar.hidden = true
    }
}
```

And then my SideMenuViewController.swift is

```
import UIKit
class SideMenuViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var homeButtonView: UIView!
  @IBOutlet weak var searchButtonView: UIView!
  @IBOutlet weak var savedButtonView: UIView!
  @IBOutlet weak var categoriesButtonView: UIView!

  var buttonColor = UIColor(red: 107.0/255.0, green: 14.0/255.0, blue: 74.0/255.0, alpha: 0.8)

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    homeButtonView.backgroundColor = buttonColor
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
  }

  @IBAction func homePressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    let tabBarController: UITabBarController? = self.parentViewController?.childViewControllers[1] as? UITabBarController
    tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
    unsetBackgroundColors()
    homeButtonView.backgroundColor = buttonColor
  }
  @IBAction func searchPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    let tabBarController: UITabBarController? = self.parentViewController?.childViewControllers[1] as? UITabBarController
    tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
    unsetBackgroundColors()
    searchButtonView.backgroundColor = buttonColor
  }

  @IBAction func savedPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    let tabBarController: UITabBarController? = self.parentViewController?.childViewControllers[1] as? UITabBarController
    tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2
    unsetBackgroundColors()
    savedButtonView.backgroundColor = buttonColor
  }

  @IBAction func categoriesPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    let tabBarController: UITabBarController? = self.parentViewController?.childViewControllers[1] as? UITabBarController
    tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 3
    unsetBackgroundColors()
    categoriesButtonView.backgroundColor = buttonColor
  }

  func unsetBackgroundColors(){
    homeButtonView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    searchButtonView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    savedButtonView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    categoriesButtonView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
let nav = tabBarController?.childViewControllers[desiredIndex] as! UINavigationController
nav.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

So the relevant part of SideMenuViewController.swift becomes:

```
func tabPressed(desiredIndex: Int){
    let tabBarController: UITabBarController? = self.parentViewController?.childViewControllers[1] as? UITabBarController
    let selectedIndex = tabBarController?.selectedIndex
    if desiredIndex != selectedIndex{
        tabBarController?.selectedIndex = desiredIndex
        unsetBackgroundColors()
    }
    else{
        let nav = tabBarController?.childViewControllers[desiredIndex] as! UINavigationController
        nav.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
}

@IBAction func homePressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    tabPressed(0)
    homeButtonView.backgroundColor = buttonColor
}
@IBAction func searchPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    tabPressed(1)
    searchButtonView.backgroundColor = buttonColor
}

@IBAction func savedPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    tabPressed(2)
    savedButtonView.backgroundColor = buttonColor
    AppDelegate().softResetBadgeCount()
}

@IBAction func categoriesPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    tabPressed(3)
    categoriesButtonView.backgroundColor = buttonColor
}
```